# Samba share with no-ip on mac osx

Tags: debian, networking, ssh, web-server

i configured my raspy to share an usb disk on my lan.

Works well...
[image]

...if i use lan address, in my lan address (`smb://192.168.0.115`) but i don't able to use no-ip dynamic dns url...

`smb://myurl.no-ip.com` won't work.

I'm also able to connect in ssh.

```
MacBook:~ albertop$ ssh pi@192.168.0.115       
pi@192.168.0.115's password: 
Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #250 PREEMPT Thu Oct 18 19:03:02 BST 2012 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Dec  8 20:30:41 2012 from 192.168.0.103
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

This the conf of smb.conf:

```
[public]
  comment = Public Storage
  path = /home/shared
  valid users = @users
  force group = users
  create mask = 0660
  directory mask = 0771
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  guest account = ftp
  browseable = yes
```

I have no-ip client installed, up and running on boot.

```
/etc/init.d/noip start
```

Raspberry has a static ip address (192.168.0.115).

What's wrong?
How can i do to connect to rasperry outside my lan?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your raspberry pi has an internal ip in the 192.168.0.0/24 range, so when you try to connect to it from the internal network everything works.
But as you might know the no-ip client grabs the external ip of your connection and redirects the hostname to this.

Have a look at www.whatismyip.com and you should find your external ip address. That said, you are probably connected to the internet via a router, and to be able to connect to you pi from the "outside" of this router, you will have to do some port forwarding in the router.

As an example: SSH works on port 22, so to be able to ssh to your pi you will need this routing:  outsideIP::22 -> Router -> RasberryPiIp:22.

You can find some info on how to forward for different routers here: http://portforward.com/routers.htm

Best luck,
B

Comment: +1 thanks man. I missed routing from out->22 to in->22. it works now.

Comment: No Problem. Happy to help!